# Send mail to users with specific field values - Drupal 9

Tags: php, drupal

In the user profile, I have an entity reference field "grant_type". This takes in the values "a,b,c,d". All these are checkboxes.

Next I have a content type named "Test content" that has the same entity reference field "grant_type". So everytime when a new content of "Test content" type is created, an email should be sent out to users who have the corresponding grant_type selected in their profile.

Example: user 1 has grant_type: b,c selected in the profile.
When a new content of "test content" type is created and that has field_grant_type selected as b or c then an email should be sent out to the user 1.

Below is my code I have tried so far:

```
function mymod_node_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if($entity->bundle() == 'test_content') {
    notify_new_items($entity, 'Created');
  }
}


function notify_new_items(EntityInterface $entity, $mode) {
  //identify fields
 
  $langcode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getDefaultLanguage()->getId();

  $recipients = [];
  $ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('roles', 'developer', 'IN') //send emails only to developer role
  ->execute();

  $users = User::loadMultiple($ids);

  $mode_info = '';

  //got user email addresses
  foreach($users as $user) {
    $username = $user->get('name')->getString();
    $mail =  $user->get('mail')->getString();
    $recipients[] = $mail;
  }

  //reading the grant type selection for each user (multiple values are allowed since its a checkbox)
      foreach($users as $user) {   
      $a[] = $user->field_grant_type->getValue();
      }


    //send email
        $params['context']['subject'] = t('[@site] Event @mode: @title', ['@site' => \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name'), '@mode' => $mode, '@event_name' => $event_or_resource_title]);
        $params['context']['message'] = $mode_info . '' .
                                        $username . ', <br />' .
                                        'Detail: '. $body;

        $s_recipients = implode(', ', $recipients);
        $to = $s_recipients;
        \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->mail('system', 'mail', $to, $langcode, $params);
}

  function smtp_mail_alter(&$message) {
    $smtp_config = \Drupal::config('smtp.settings');
    if ($smtp_config->get('smtp_allowhtml')) {
      $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes';
    }
  }
```

This code sends out the email to everyone in the "developer" role. How can I filter the email to send to users who has only selected a specific grant type?

Behavior: If a user has selected grant_type "a" that user should only be notified when a content is created with grant type "a". Pls suggest on how to implement the grant type preference.

Comment: Maybe adding a condition on your user query.

Comment: like..filtering for role and granttype together?

Comment: @2pha can you please elaborate some more?